# Ionic can't run ionic platform android

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I am starting to follow [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) demo for learning the ionic framework.

I made it to the point where it suggests that I type in `ionic platform android`. When I type that, I get this error:

```
C02FF724DF91:todo jcorser$ ionic platform android
Creating android project...

/Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at /Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:158:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
Error: /Users/jcorser/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

I am on Mac OSX. I have developed two android apps before using Android Studio. I also followed the suggestion for OSX on the manual `$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: `Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH.`

Comment: Yes that appears to be my problem! Do you know how to solve it? I searched this section of the error messages and didn't get anything useful from google.

Comment: do you have an installed android sdk ?

Comment: Yes I do. I seem to have found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170288/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-on-mac-os?rq=1). My question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you installed Android SDK via Homebrew, then the fix is this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=`brew --prefix android`
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, spent hours looking for a solution :-S Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear. You'll need to put this in your .bashrc or .zshrc file.

Comment: to install via brew "brew install android-sdk"

Comment: Thanks . finally it worked for me .. I spoiled 48 hours :) and in 48 seconds this answer solved my problem.

Comment: You saved me! Any ideas on how

Answer (score 10):

on macosx it will be like this

**step1**

open and edit the profile

```
    vi ~/.bash_profile
```

**step2**

the bash_profile would be like below (this is my edition)

```
    export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Zam/Documents/android-sdk-macosx
    export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

for you, it shuold use your sdk location

```
    export ANDROID_HOME=where your sdk location
    export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

**step3**

refresh

```
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows set the `ANDROID_HOME` in System Variables

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Android SDK via Homebrew, then fix  this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=`brew --prefix android`
```