# Cordova error when trying to add plugin with the android.support.v4 dependency

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

It does work at Microsoft but when i switch to the Mac i faced the problem when i trying to add the same plugin. I getting the same error many days already and can't fix. Hope can get some help. Thanks.

Things i have tried are:-

- android sdk manager install all android support library, resource those
- uninstall, reinstall platform and plugin
- straight download the plugin of android.support.v4 ( it can be install but the plugin need this dependency doesn't work correctly )
- asked the official support from pushbots ( suggested me to uninstall and reinstall but it still the same )
- [cordova platform add android - Not working on Mac Os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170288/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-on-mac-os)

  ```
  bash-3.2# cordova plugin add com.pushbots.push
  Fetching plugin "com.pushbots.push" via cordova plugins registry
  Installing "com.pushbots.push" for android
  WARNING: android.support.v4 has been renamed to cordova-plugin-android-support-v4. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you `cordova plugin rm android.support.v4` and `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-support-v4`.
  Fetching plugin "android.support.v4" via cordova plugins registry
  npm http GET http://cordova.iriscouch.com/registry/_design/app/_rewrite/android.support.v4/-/android.support.v4-21.0.1.tgz
  npm http 404 http://cordova.iriscouch.com/registry/_design/app/_rewrite/android.support.v4/-/android.support.v4-21.0.1.tgz
  npm ERR! fetch failed http://cordova.iriscouch.com/registry/_design/app/_rewrite/android.support.v4/-/android.support.v4-21.0.1.tgz
  Fetching from cordova plugins registry failed: 404 Not Found
  Fetching plugin "android.support.v4" via npm
  npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/android.support.v4
  npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/android.support.v4
  Fetching from npm failed: 404 Not Found: android.support.v4
  Failed to install 'com.pushbots.push':Error: 404 Not Found: android.support.v4
      at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:268:14)
      at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
      at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
      at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
      at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
      at _stream_readable.js:908:16
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
  Error: 404 Not Found: android.support.v4
      at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:268:14)
      at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
      at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
      at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
      at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
      at _stream_readable.js:908:16
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm update
cordova plugin add com.pushbots.push
```